# whats wrong with this array map via typescript syntax

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have the following state declaration:

```
constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        orders: []
    };
}
```

where orders is an array of these Order structures:

```
interface Order {
    symbol: string,
    qty: number,
    side: Side
}
```

I want to map over the orders array like so:

```
this.state.orders.map( ( {order}, index: number) => {
    return <li key={index}>order.symbol order.qty</li>;
})
```

I am playing with parenthesis and curlys, cant get the syntax right, not quite sure what I am doing.  My intent is "loop over the array of orders in the render method and display it"

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to destruct `order` in your `map` function. In your current syntax, `map` is expecting an object that has an `order` property for each element in the `orders` array.

You can simply remove the curly braces to access each `order`. Also, make sure you use curly braces in your JSX to differentiate between text and JS expression:

```
this.state.orders.map( (order: Order, index: number) => {
    return <li key={index}>{order.symbol} {order.qty}</li>;
})
```

See more about [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring).

Comment: thank you, this is great -- it fixes all red squiggles , but one.  For "this.state" it shows [ts] ':' expected.
(property) this: any

Comment: It sounds like it may need the type of each element in the map to be explicit, so something like `(order: Order, index: number): JSX.Element` or `(order: Order, index: number): any` if the former does not work

Comment: No, Christian, your suggestion does not change anything -- the addition of what you are suggesting does not seem to hurt, but the period in this.state is still red, still complaining.  thank you

Comment: Never mind, there was another set of curlys around my map statement -- I thought they were a no-op, but I guess not.   thank you

Answer (score 1):

It would be :

```
this.state.orders.map( ( { symbol, qty }, index: number) => {
    return <li key={index}>{symbol} {qty}</li>;
})
```